# Do I need to use induction to have sufficient rigor in this proof?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, induction

I'm taking my first analysis class this summer.  The professor asked us to prove that $a^{2n}-b^{2n}$ is divisible by $a+b$.  After dorking around with the first couple of $n$ I was able to come up with a general term for the factorization of $a^{2n}-b^{2n}$.  What I got was:

$$ a^{2n}-b^{2n}=(a+b)\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}(-1)^ka^{2n-1-k}b^k$$
I proceeded with the proof as follows:

$$ \implies \sum_0^{2n-1}(-1)^ka^{2n-k}b^k+\sum_0^{2n-1}(-1)^ka^{2n-1-k}b^{k+1}   $$

$$ =a^{2n}+\sum_1^{2n-1}(-1)^ka^{2n-k}b^k+\sum_0^{2n-2}(-1)^ka^{2n-1-k}b^{k+1}-b^{2n} $$

Now shifting indicies on the second sum, and rearranging:

$$ \implies a^{2n}-b^{2n}+\sum_1^{2n-1}(-1)^ka^{2n-k}b^k+\sum_1^{2n-1}(-1)^{k-1}a^{2n-k}b^{k}$$

Then pulling out a $-1$ from the second sum we see that the two sums kill each other and we are left with $a^{2n}-b^{2n}$.  It seemed like a reasonable proof to me but is lacking rigor apparently because I did not show that it holds for $n+1$.  However, showing the proof for an arbitrary $n$ seemed good enough to me as we can pick any $n$ and know that there is divisibility.  What am I missing?  Why is showing a proof for an arbitrary $n$ not good enough?  Is induction the only way to prove this?

Comment: Looks reasonable to me.

Comment: Why do you think so? Because of the reason I stated?  @rogerl

Comment: For your argument to be completely rigorous, one must already have a rigorous definition of the summation operator. It can be defined by recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, try this simpler proof:

The polynomial reminder theorem states that $(x-c)$ is a divisor of a polynomial $f(x)$ if and only if $f(a)=0$. Let $x=a$, $f(a)=a^{2n}-b^{2n}$ and $c=-b$. Therefore $(a+b)$ is a divisor of $f(a)$ if and only if $f(-b)=0$. $f(-b)=(-b)^{2n}-b^{2n}=0$. So therefore $(a+b)$ divides $a^{2n}-b^{2n}$.